# Unwanted worksheet duplication VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I built a code into a command button that identified a single sheet, copies the values and the formulas, and creates a separate detached workbook that we use for ordering material. The original formula worked great and was simple when there was only 1 target sheet. I have added 4 additional sheets to be captured, the core of the formula still works and it copies/detaches a separate workbook for ordering, but now it is also creating a copy of the original workbook as well for no reason.

How can I get it to only copy and detach the sheets in the formula and not the entire workbook?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     ' Plain_Copy Macro '
     Sheets("PROCUREMENT").Visible = True
     Sheets("Request").Visible = True
     Sheets("LISTS").Visible = True
     Sheets("Copy").Visible = True

    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
    Dim TempWindow As Window
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
        Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
        .Sheets(Array("REQUESTOR", "PROCUREMENT", "Request", "LISTS", "Copy")).Copy

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws.UsedRange
                .Copy
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End With
            TempWindow.Close
        Next ws

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
```

Comment: Which one exactly is the "copy of the original worksheet"? Side note, you keep using "formula" but it sounds like you mean "code".

Comment: Sorry man I'm still kind of new to coding. Its all self taught as you can probably tell lol Were you wanting the original code that I used? or are you asking which section of this code copies the original

Comment: I'm asking: you have `Array("REQUESTOR", "PROCUREMENT", "Request", "LISTS", "Copy")`. So what is (presumably) the sixth sheet that gets copied over?

Comment: Those are the only sheets that need to be copied and detached

Comment: Right, so in the new workbook, what is the name of the additional, unwanted sheet?

Comment: Bad use of words in my description. Its not a "worksheet", its the entire workbook that is being copied along with the worksheets that I need. I need to tell it to not copy the entire workbook as its copying the sheets.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How does one copy a workbook along with a worksheet?

Comment: So from the original workbook, its creating the copy that I need with all of the info and sheets, but also creating a whole new workbook for no reason.. sorry about that.

Comment: `.Sheets(Array("REQUESTOR", "PROCUREMENT", "Request", "LISTS", "Copy")).Copy` creates a new workbook.

Comment: That's where I am stuck.. the original workbook has 14 sheets, those 5 sheets in the formula are the ones that need to be copied and detached to order, the code does that just fine, but then when that part is finished, this code is making another duplicate workbook with those 14 tabs again and including all of the formulas, codes, values etc.

Comment: I'd remove `Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow` and `Set TempWindow = .NewWindow`

Comment: I had a feeling that was the issue.. Thanks a lot Ben. I removed those earlier today when i was adjusting this and it kept throwing up error codes. Now its working fine